# Criar Trigger update MySQL

Tags: mysql

Tenho duas tabelas uma apartamento a outra contrato. Quando o status do contrato for alterado pra `off`. O status do apartamento fica livre. Tenho uma chave estrangeira na tabela contrato para relacionar com apartamento.

Gostaria de saber como faço para criar um trigger para atualizar um campo da tabela apartamento depois de atualizar um campo da tabela contrato.

```
DELIMITER // 
CREATE TRIGGER upd_tab_b BEFORE UPDATE ON tab_b FOR EACH ROW BEGIN 
UPDATE tab_a 
SET campo_a = livre 
WHERE 1 = 1; 
-- a dúvida é como dizer atualize --quando o campo da tabela B for --igual a off
END;
// DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Ramon, poderia dar mais detalhes de que tipos de informações você irá atualizar?

Comment: Talvez você precise de trigger em ambas tabela, onde a primeira trigger manda um update que atualiza a segunda trigger.... não sei... com mais detalhes fica melhor pra te direcionar.

Comment: Ok. Bom tenho duas tabelas uma apartamento a outra contrato. Quando o status do contrato for alterado pra off. O status do apartamento fica livre. Tenho uma chave estrangeira na tabela contrato para relacionar com apartamento.

Comment: A duvida é como digo atualize o tabA.campo = livre where tabB.campo = off and tabA.id = tabB.id

Comment: Prefira [edit] sua pergunta ao invés de deixar os detalhes somente no comentário. Ajuda bastante para os próximos que forem ler sua dúvida. Procure fazer um [tour] para entender melhor como melhorar suas perguntar ;)

Answer (score 2):

Na prática, para setar o campo `tab_a.campo_a = tab_b.campo_b + 1`, ficaria mais ou menos assim:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER upd_tab_b BEFORE UPDATE ON tab_b
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE tab_a SET campo_a = NEW.campo_b + 1
    WHERE 1 = 1; -- informe suas condições
END;//
DELIMITER ;
```

Vale a penar dar uma olhada na sintaxe de uma [trigger](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/trigger-syntax.html).

Comment: Boa resposta mas não é a condição que eu falei. Despois de mudar o status em um campo da tabela B a tringger tem que alterar o status do campo da tabela A

Comment: Ramon, basta você saber qual a chave (foreign key) que interliga as duas tabelas e usar na condição. Pode ter certeza que irá funcionar.

Comment: Vitor nao funcionou

Comment: BEGIN
IF new.status_aluguel = 'cerrado'
UPDATE apartamento 
SET status_apart = 'libre' 
WHERE  id_apart = new.apartamento_id_apart;
end if;
END

Comment: Caro Ramon, você fez uma pergunta genérica e eu respondi. Agora você editou a pergunta, especificando o contexto, o que mudaria o tom da resposta. Quando for assim, por favor, faça outra pergunta. Leia esse guia para entender o funcionamento básico do StackOverflow pt.stackoverflow.com/tour