# Como saber quais colunas foram modificadas em um UPDATE usando TRIGGER?

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados, trigger

Boa tarde pessoal.

Estou criando uma TRIGGER AFTER UPDATE em uma tabela no BD, e preciso saber quais colunas foram alteradas (independente do valor que foi colocado), e colocar os nomes das colunas numa variável que irá ser inserida em uma outra tabela.

O problema é que se trata de uma tabela com muitas colunas, e ficaria muito feio fazer a checagem coluna por coluna dessa forma:

```
IF (NEW.Column!= OLD.Column) THEN

    SET @ColunasAlteradas = CONCAT(@ColunasAlteradas, ', NomeColunaAlterada');

END IF;
```

Tô com a ideia de fazer uma loucura e utilizar STMT e CURSOR na tabela COLUMNS do information_schema, mas se tiver alguma função que faça essa checagem em uma TRIGGER ajudaria demais.

Obrigado desde já!

Comment: O que está querendo fazer? Me parece um log, é isso? Veja se isso não te ajuda...https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/143720/criar-trigger-update-mysql

Answer (score 3):

Creio que terá que fazer as verificações uma a uma, por exemplo:

```
@IF (OLD.column != NEW.column) SET `outraColuna` = OLD.outraColuna + 1;
```

Algo assim